# Multiple JFrames

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am making an application for processing customer orders(in java).
My program has 3 `JFrame` windows (Yes I know its not a good idea to use multiple frames, but they aren't really connected to each other).

1. Main one: Here you select what you are (Customer or Operator)
2. Customer `JFrame`
3. Operator `JFrame`

After a Customer makes an order ( main frame > customer frame > complete order(button). I am doing something like this:

```
customerframe.dispose();
customerframe.revalidate();
customerframe.repaint();
reloadframe(); ///a method which reinitializes the frame (Note: I am doing a frame=new JFrame()  here)
mainframe.setVisible(true);
```

I select customer again it opens the `customerframe` but the problem is that the listeners don`t work anymore, I guess they somehow remain connected to the old frame or something.

I have been trying to make it work for some hours now...

Comment: I have already read it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not be using multiple `JFrames` See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-or-bad) link for more info.

Instead, I suggest you use a [CardLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) as demonstrated here:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class MainFrame
{
    static JPanel homeContainer;
    static CardLayout cl;

    JPanel homePanel;
    JPanel otherPanel;


    public MainFrame()
    {
        JFrame mFrame = new JFrame("CardLayout Example");
        JButton showOtherPanelBtn = new JButton("Show Other Panel");
        JButton backToHomeBtn = new JButton("Show Home Panel");

        cl = new CardLayout(5, 5);
        homeContainer = new JPanel(cl);
        homeContainer.setBackground(Color.black);

        homePanel = new JPanel();
        homePanel.setBackground(Color.blue);
        homePanel.add(showOtherPanelBtn);

        homeContainer.add(homePanel, "Home");

        otherPanel = new JPanel();
        otherPanel.setBackground(Color.green);
        otherPanel.add(backToHomeBtn);

        homeContainer.add(otherPanel, "Other Panel");

        showOtherPanelBtn.addActionListener(e -> cl.show(homeContainer, "Other Panel"));
        backToHomeBtn.addActionListener(e -> cl.show(homeContainer, "Home"));

        mFrame.add(homeContainer);
        cl.show(homeContainer, "Home");
        mFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        mFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        mFrame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        mFrame.pack();
        mFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(MainFrame::new);
    }
}
```

With a Cardlayout, you switch between JPanel's instead. This way, you don't have to create a new JFrame, just to display new content. Basically, you have some sort of container, (Could be the `JFrame` or could be a `JPanel`) and then, when you add the other panels that you create, you give them a name. You can then switch between the panels using `cardLayout.show(container, "Name");`

Comment: So its impossible to make it work with Multiple JFrames ?

Comment: It is not impossible, just not recommended. Using a cardlayout will be much easier in the long run. You can switch views with one line of code in an action listener.